# F# searching in trees F#

Tags: recursion, tree, f#, functional-programming

Find an 'item/object/type' in a recursive tree type, the tree type is UNSORTED, thus binary search operation is not going to succeed.

```ml
Type Tree = T of (Name*Children)
And Children = Tree list
//findTree :Tree*Name -> Tree
```

My code(which doesn't work)

```ml
let rec findTree t n = List.find(fun (T(nameTree,childTree)) -> n=nameTree ) t
```

I've tried using recursion and auxFunctions, but it ends up being very messy with no success.

Comment: Is this tagged with [haskell] because you're looking for Haskell implementations as well?

Comment: If you have, then yes please, or just functional pseudo-code :)

I've been told by my professor that F# is microsofts version of haskall, so I presume the similarities are high.(as opposed to object-oriented)

Comment: So I will admit that I'm not very familiar with F#, I'm a Haskell guy, so would this type be equivalent to the type `data Tree = T Name [Tree]` (essentially a [rose tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_tree))?

Comment: Seems close, a tree with 0..n children that is unordered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your base type is essentially this (cleaned up missing types):

```
type Tree = 
    | Tree of (string * Tree list)
```

Now the tree is unsorted, so the best you can do is a linear search, recursively going down the child nodes until a match is found. In the following case, the search goes depth-first:

```
[<CompilationRepresentationAttribute(CompilationRepresentationFlags.ModuleSuffix)>]
module Tree = 
    let find p tree = 
        let rec findInner t =
            match t with
            | Tree(n, _) when p(n) -> Some(t)
            | Tree(_, children) -> children |> Seq.choose (findInner) 
                                            |> Seq.tryFind (fun _ -> true)
            | Tree(_, []) -> None
        findInner tree
```

You can use `List.choose` and `List.tryFind` if you want, I used `Seq` so it would stop early on `tryFind`.
Also, this version has a predicate match on name. If you *always* want to use equality, you can add the name as parameter and swap `p` for `name` and `when p(n)` to `when n = name`.

Now, a little test:

```
let tree = Tree("A", 
                [Tree("B", 
                    [Tree("C",[]); 
                     Tree("D", 
                        [Tree("E",[])])
                    ]); 
                Tree("F",[])
                ])

tree |> Tree.find (fun n -> n = "B") |> printfn "%A"
tree |> Tree.find (fun n -> n = "D") |> printfn "%A"
tree |> Tree.find (fun n -> n = "E") |> printfn "%A"
tree |> Tree.find (fun n -> n = "TEST") |> printfn "%A"
tree |> Tree.find (fun n -> n = "F") |> printfn "%A"
```

Which prints, respectively:

```
Some (Tree ("B", [Tree ("C", []); Tree ("D", [Tree ("E", [])])]))
Some (Tree ("D", [Tree ("E", [])]))
Some (Tree ("E", []))
<null>
Some (Tree ("F", []))
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how you use the Seq/List.choose(function) |> Seq/List.tryFind (fun _ -> true) ??

Comment: @user3711518 Apply a chooser `'T->'U option` to obtain a filtered _and_ mapped sequence, and return the first element of it as `'U option`. Can be replaced by `Seq.tryPick`.

Comment: @kaefer True, I completely forgot about `tryPick` :)